# How can I tell Android to read from a different resourse for different Api levels?

Tags: android, xml, string, api

Is there any way that I can customize my app so that it loads its strings from different 
strins.xml files for different Android versions?

I know about locales and that is NOT what I'm looking for.
I want android to get its strings from strings_a.xml when Api level is 11 or lower and
from strings_b.xml with api levels 12+.

I am not willing to check for android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT in my code everywhere I am setting a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name your resource directories based on the Android version, so have **values** for the older Android versions, and **values-v12** for the more recent ones.

It's all explained at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: Thanks a lot tihs is exactly what I was looking for and couldn't find on developers page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create directory values-v11 or values-v14 in the res folder of your project and put your strings.xml and refer the string item using :

```
getResources().getString(
```